# Django postgresql, filter on DateTime field with gt and lt lookups doesn't work

Tags: django, postgresql

I have problem with filtering on Datetime field with `lt` and `gt` lookups. I use following code:

```
timeout_range = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(seconds=settings.USER_ONLINE_TIMEOUT)              
if friend_filter == "offline":
            friends.filter(friend__info__last_active__lt=timeout_range)
elif friend_filter == "online":
            friends.filter(friend__info__last_active__gt=timeout_range)
```

In both cases, it returns same result and seems like it doesn't filter anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the `filter` to a queryset returns a new queryset and does not modify the existing queryset. Since you don't assign the new queryset to a variable, I am assuming that you simply access the `friends` variable afterwards which is still the original queryset. Assign the result of `filter(...)` to the `friends` variable to access it later.

```
if friend_filter == "offline":
    friends = friends.filter(friend__info__last_active__lt=timeout_range)
elif friend_filter == "online":
    friends = friends.filter(friend__info__last_active__gt=timeout_range)
```